# Bower package resolve library conflict

Tags: npm, bower, ember-cli

I have my app which used jQuery version 1.11.1. Now I installed a typeahead component as Bower package and that seems to be dependent on different jQuery version (v 1.9).

I find it very confusing to resolve the same. It says

```
Unable to find a suitable version for jquery, please choose one:
    1) jquery#~1.9 which resolved to 1.9.1 and is required by typeahead.js#0.9.3
    2) jquery#^1.11.1 which resolved to 1.11.3 and is required by myapp
    3) jquery#^1.11.3 which resolved to 1.11.3 and is required by ember-truth-helpers#1.2.0
    4) jquery#>=1.2 which resolved to 2.1.4 and is required by jquery-cookie#1.4.1
    5) jquery#>=1.6 which resolved to 2.1.4 and is required by jquery-ui#1.11.4
    6) jquery#>= 1.9.1 which resolved to 2.1.4 and is required by bootstrap#3.3.5
    7) jquery#>= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0 which resolved to 2.1.4 and is required by ember#1.13.3
```

How can I understand the above messages and what is the best way to resolve such conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

You can go with **jquery#^1.11.3 which resolved to 1.11.3** and it should be working. jQuery API is really reliable for Ember, so your app should be working with all versions you see in that message.

Comment: but could u pls help me understand these messages in general !

Comment: Your application is build on top of many libraries which often are not being always up to date with latest versions. However many libraries you use depend on jQuery. Each library you depend on may require different version range for jQuery and that's what happened in your case.